# DISTINCT is not working for SELECT query in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

Here i have the invoice details table.
I need the all values without duplicate of `[invoiceno]`.
I am try

```
select distinct invoiceno,name,addr1,addr2,id from invoice_table;
```

Result:

```
invoiceno    name             addr1       addr2             id
2016718001  Severus Sanpe   7,Hogwards, Sevilee,USA 7451    5
2016718002  Severus Sanpe   7,Hogwards, Sevilee,USA 7451    8
2016718002  Severus Sanpe   7,Hogwards, Sevilee,USA 7451    9
```

I want the result:

```
 invoiceno   name             addr1       addr2             id
2016718001  Severus Sanpe   7,Hogwards, Sevilee,USA 7451    5
2016718002  Severus Sanpe   7,Hogwards, Sevilee,USA 7451    8
```

It's working fine without `id` in `SELECT`. But i need that also. 
How to do this?

Comment: see the id, it is 9 for 3rd entry.

Comment: The id column is different which is why it comes up twice

Comment: A `distinct` works on an entire row, hence it occurs twice. The row is unique.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry I'm using mssql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want a GROUP BY query with MIN aggregated function:

```
select
  invoiceno, name, addr1, addr2, min(id) as id
from
  invoice_table
group by
  invoiceno, name, addr1, addr2
```

or if the same invoice can have multiple names and/or addresses, you can use something like this:

```
select t.invoiceno, t.name, t.addr1, t.addr2, t.id
from
  invoice_table t inner join (select invoiceno, min(id) as min_id) m
  on t.invoiceno=m.invoiceno and t.id=m.min_id
```

this will return the first id (the one with the lowest value) for every invoiceno.

Comment: What about the case when there are other differences, other than the ID? You need another trick here.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want `invoiceno` duplicated, then a typical method is to use `row_number()`:

```
select iv.*
from (select iv.*, row_number() over (partition by invoiceno order by id desc) as seqnum
      from invoice_table iv
     ) iv
where seqnum = 1 ;
```

You are misunderstanding how `select distinct` works.  It works on *all* columns (and expressions) in the `select` list, including `id`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want only 1 entry per invoice. 
Assuming it is SQL Server 2008 or later

```
select * from (
select invoiceno,name,addr1,addr2,id, Row_number() over( partition by invoiceno order by invoiceno) RN from invoice_table
) a where Rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM invoice_table  where ID IN(
SELECT MIN(ID)  FROM invoice_table
GROUP BY invoiceno,name,addr1,addr2)

Answer (score 0):

The `DISTINCT` keyword applies to the full result set: `invoiceno,name,addr1,addr2,id`. Lines 2 and 3 differ at id field, so they will be distinct.

There are two options for this:

1. Skip the ID
2. Pre-filter ID-s with a subselect

Obviously, you can skip the id field like this:

```
select distinct invoiceno,name,addr1,addr2 from invoice_table;
```

The grouping is a little more tricky:

```
select invoiceno,name,addr1,addr2,id -- no distinct
from invoice_table
where id in (
    select min(id) from invoice_table
    group by invoiceno -- we have this group by + min instead of the distinct keyword
)
```

This second one might have negative impact on your performance, so be careful with this.